# PAM account interface vs /etc/shadow

Tags: security, password, pam

According to the official Red Had [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_smart_cards/pam_configuration_files) on `pam` for the `account` interface:

> account — This module interface verifies that access is allowed. For example, it checks if a user account has expired or if a user is allowed to log in at a particular time of day.

However, similar information (on account validity) is incorporated in `/etc/shadow` file. As the `tldp` [pages](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html) mention, some of the last fields include:

> The number of days after password expires that account is disabled
>
> The number of days since January 1, 1970 that an account has been
>   disabled
>
> A reserved field for possible future use

So when does an application (even a PAM-enabled one) reside to when checking account validity?

What happens when rules in `/etc/pam.d/application` may contradict `/etc/shadow`?

Comment: I'm not sure but PAM can use different backend in order and it will match the first one in the list making the other usless if another backend then etc/shadow matchs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally */etc/{group,passwd,shadow}* are not used directly, but rather through `pam`. You can think of `pam` as kind of a connector that can be configured to use different backends like the */etc/{group,passwd,shadow}* things or LDAP to query user information.

To make `pam` work this way, each backend does have a pam module that can query the backend and retrieve information.
The very basic configuration of `pam` is to use the `pam_unix.so` module which retrieves the information from `/etc/{group,passwd,shadow}` files.

You can also read more about the capabilities of `the pam_unix.so`in `man pam_unix`.